# Why bss has some value in this case?

Tags: c

I saw this in some website and was surprised with the result:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    return 0;
}
```

When the above code is checked for memory in each sections using `size`

```
$ gcc memory-layout.c -o memory-layout
$ size memory-layout
text       data        bss        dec        hex    filename
960        248          8       1216        4c0    memory-layout
```

Here,
    without any global or static variables, the size of `bss` is shown `8`. I didn't get for what this 8 bytes are used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking at the segment sizes for the full executable program: the object module for your source code is linked to the standard library startup code and the necessary library support functions, such as `exit`.  The numbers you see for `data` and `bss` are probably due to global objects defined by these modules.  Note in particular that your `main` function hardly justifies 960 bytes of code.

Generate just an object file and run `size` on that:

```
$ gcc -c memory-layout.c
$ size memory-layout.o
```